# How to get the counted numbers of properties from object literals?

Tags: javascript, object, literals

// Javascript 
// Using object literal

```
var kids = {
    dipok: "nursery",
    bonku: "LKG-1",
    jaya: "LKG-2",
    Raj_Kumar: "nursery"
}
```

> **"I have written this above object literal now i want to display the number of nursery kids eg.- 2 What is the thing i need to display"**

I have tried this code but it is false as much as i can assume

// I have this code being tired to use

```
var kkr = (kids.dipok).toString.length,count;
if(kkr>=1){
    ++count;
    console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are u trying to do? And also toString is a function

Comment: It might be worth to rephrase your question it doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of times a value appears in an object get the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the properties that have a matching value, and return the length.

```js
var kids = {
  dipok: "nursery",
  bonku: "LKG-1",
  jaya: "LKG-2",
  Raj_Kumar: "nursery"
};

function countValue(obj, value) {
  return Object.values(obj).filter(v => v === value).length;
}

const out = countValue(kids, 'nursery');
console.log(out);
```